# How do I expand CMake list to multiple values?

Tags: cmake

I would like to use `list` operation with `REMOVE_ITEM` and multiple values in order to remove the file names of temporary files which are created by Emacs.

```
aux_source_directory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src SOURCES)
file(GLOB TMP_FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/.#*")
list(REMOVE_ITEM SOURCES TMP_FILES)
```

But `list` does not accept `list` as an argument, so the example above does not work as expected.

How do I expand a `list` to multiple values in this case?

Ref. http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/list.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `list` command you want the [value of the variable](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-language.7.html#variable-references) `TMP_FILES` so you should use :

```
list(REMOVE_ITEM SOURCES ${TMP_FILES})
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was just my easy mistake! It now works as expected.